# jqWidgets combobox value issue with form

Tags: php, combobox, jqwidget, jqxwidgets, jqxcombobox

There is demo [Demo link](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/php/index.htm?(arctic)#demos/php/combobox.htm) showing how JQWidget jqxcombobox is working with form submission. But if we look the demo closely we can see the results are changing when we use mouse or keyboard.

For example Alfreds Futterkiste is the Display Member and value is Maria Anders.
We will get the correct value (Maria Andres) when we submit the form using Mouse click, if we use the keyboard we get the same Display-member value Alfreds Futterkiste.

I  think if i can add a hidden text box with below code then it may work.
Bind to the change by type: jqxComboBox.

```
$('#jqxComboBox').on('change', function (event) 
{
    var args = event.args;
    if (args) {
    // index represents the item's index.                          
    var index = args.index;
    var item = args.item;
    // get item's label and value.
    var label = item.label;
    var value = item.value;
}
});
```

But how I populate the hidden text box with the above function...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself :)

I found a small solution for this....
1. Create a hidden field to store the value of the combobox
2. Use event.args.item.value to change the value of the hidden field.

```
// trigger the select event.
                $("#combobox").on('select', function (event) {
                var elem = document.getElementById("mytext");
elem.value = event.args.item.value;
```

in Body

```
 <form class="form" id="form" target="form-iframe"  method="post" action="echo.php" style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana; width: 650px;">        
 <div name="list" id="combobox">
 <input name="productvalue" type="hidden" id="mytext">
  <input style="margin-top: 10px;" type="submit" value="Submit" id="sendButton" /> 
  </form>
```

echo.php

```
<?php
        echo "Wrong Data =";
    echo $_POST["list"];
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Value through hidden feild =";
    echo $_POST["productvalue"];

?>
```

hope this will work for someone :)